# API response returns 0 in Postman, but -0.0 when calling from C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm making a call to an API using C# code.

I have an API class that has a GET method. (I admit that I got the code from a colleague and have just adapted it).

[image: GET method]

The ProcessRequest method takes the response from the WebRequest and stores it in a variable called `feed`

When I use the text visualizer to see what is coming back, then I see the `item` key-value pair has a -0.0 value.

[image: ProcessRequest method]
[image: Visual Studio tooltip value]

This unfortunately gives an error when I use Newtonsoft to deserialise into a class that I have defined as this field should be an integer. **NOTE: THE ERROR NEWTONSOFT RETURNS IS IRRELEVANT TO ME AT THIS POINT**

When I call the API using Postman, this is the result I get back ...

[image: Postman response]

You can see that the `last` KVP returns an integer value, which is what is expected.

Does anyone have any idea of why I am getting a different response in my C# code than I am from Postman, and what I can do about it?

Summary:-
C# returns me a -0.0 in the value of that Key-Value pair
Postman returns me a 0 in the value of that Key-Value pair

I'm unable to post a working code sample that hits the API as the API is a pay-for service.

Comment: It's not really "C#" that's returning the different value. It's the API. Presumably it's responding to some difference in the requests, e.g. User-Agent headers. I suggest you ask the API provider for details.

Comment: My first guess is that postman treats -0 and 0 as the same value, whereas the C# .NET function returns the actual response.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (with code as text).

Comment: @cometbill use Fiddler or another debugging proxy to see what's actually being sent and what the *actual* response is. You posted a screenshot of the parsed POSTMAN response, not the *raw* HTTP response. Perhaps there's a difference in the two requests? Or POSTMAN just converted the decimal 0 to an integer 0?

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes, thank you. I had assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that it was my C# code that might be at fault, but yes, Postman might be parsing the result. I will contact the API provider again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman will prettify the result.

Clicking the Raw button, shows the -0.0 value coming back from the API provider, just as the C# code hinted at.

[image: Postman Raw response]